# Select results who have value more than ">" in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have an index Elasticsearch with videos objects inside, how I can select the results who have more than X "views" (i dont find any filters for this in the doc) ? 
I mean like `select * from videos where views > '99';` in mysql.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the qleasticsearch [query DSL](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/) reference. Sounds like you are looking for a [range filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/range-filter/).

Comment: I have some query like this `$array_search['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must']['term'] = array('activ' => 1)` there is no way to do the same with "`>`" ?

Comment: the term query only returns matches for a specific term, and doesn't even support text analysis. Therefore, the answer is no :)